# How to Animate Image Switch in ImageView JavaFx without adding more panes

Tags: java, image, animation, javafx, imageview

I am really bad with animations in JavaFx, any way i kinda know how to do it, problem is i would end up using a stackPane, creating a diferent ImageView for each image and switching by doing something like this:

```
  KeyValue kv= new KeyValue(slotView[i].translateYProperty(), 0, Interpolator.EASE_IN);
  KeyFrame kf= new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),kv);
  timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
  timeline.play();
```

However considring i am coding a slot with many reels and a roulette, using this would mean creating too many Panes, and I am quite sure, there has to be an easy way of doing it. So for example, how would i add an animation like a slot reel (new image entering the imageView from top to bottom) in a case like this.

````
                  for (int i = 0; i < slotResult.length; i++) {
                        switch (slotResult[i]) {
                            case "Diamond" -> {
                                slotView[i].setImage(diamondImg);
                            }
                            case "Gold" -> {
                                slotView[i].setImage(goldImg);
                            }
                            case "Money" -> {
                                slotView[i].setImage(moneyImg);
                            }
                            case "Coin" -> {
                                slotView[i].setImage(coinImg);
                            }
                            case "Bell" -> {
                                slotView[i].setImage(bellImg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
    ```
````

Comment: Having one image exit while another one enters will likely require at least two `ImageView`s. Unless you can find a way to have all the images in one image (e.g. like they're stacked on top of each other) and then simply animate the `viewport` of the `ImageView`. Haven't tried that myself though.

Comment: _I am really bad with animations in JavaFx_ then work through appropriate tutorials to improve, it's impossible to build the penthouse without building the floors below :) _too many_ panes - why and by what metric? Make it work first (llearning along the way) and then have doubts about memory/performance profile the app to find/fix bottlenecks.

Comment: @Slaw well, interacting with the view port seams to be a very good idea, in fact you made me realise that probably thats the way slot machines work (they have all the incons in a single image). Another option would be just fake the animation with a gift and after a second just change the gift for the real result.

Comment: Just note that for the view-port solution, I think you'd need the first image to be the same as the last (i.e. duplicate it) in order to make a "continuous" animation smooth.